# How to add an operator<< for templated class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I need to add operator<< to make my cout working.

Code template.cpp:

```
#include "maptemplate.h"

int main(void)
{
typedef unsigned int ID;                            //Identification number of Employee
map_template<ID,Employee> Database;                 //Database of employees

Database.Add(761028073,Employee("Jan Kowalski","salesman",28));     //Add first employee: name: Jan Kowalski, position: salseman, age: 28,
Database.Add(510212881,Employee("Adam Nowak","storekeeper",54));    //Add second employee: name: Adam Nowak, position: storekeeper, age: 54
Database.Add(730505129,Employee("Anna Zaradna","secretary",32));    //Add third employee: name: Anna Zaradna, position: secretary, age: 32

//cout << Database << endl;                         //Print databese

//map_template<ID,Employee> NewDatabase = Database; //Make a copy of database

Employee* pE;
pE = Database.Find(510212881);       //Find employee using its ID
pE->Position = "salesman";          //Modify the position of employee
pE = Database.Find(761028073);     //Find employee using its ID
pE->Age = 29;             //Modify the age of employee

//Database = NewDatabase;    //Update original database

///cout << Database << endl;  //Print original database
cout<<"Wszystko dziala"<<endl;
}
```

Code: template.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Początek klasy Employee bez template
class Employee
{
 private:
 public:
 Employee(string Name, string Position, int Age);
 string Name;
 int Age;
 string Position;

}; // koniec klasy employee

// Dodanie pól Name, Age, Position
Employee::Employee(string Name, string Position, int Age)
{
this->Name = Name;
this->Age = Age;
this->Position = Position;
}

template <class Key, class T> // template <klucze, dane pracownikow>
class map_template
{
private:
vector<Key> keys; // vector do przechowywania unikalnych kluczy pracowników
vector<T> content; // vector do przechowywania danych pracowników
public:
map_template()
{
}
void Add(Key key, T t);
T* Find(Key key);
}; // koniec klasy map_template

// Dodanie do bazy (Add)
template <class Key, class T>
void map_template<Key, T>::Add(Key key, T t)
{
keys.push_back(key);
content.push_back(t);
}
// Szukanie w bazie (Find)
template <class Key, class T>
T* map_template<Key, T>::Find(Key key)
     {
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
        if (keys[i] == key)
        {
            return &content.at(i);
        }
    return nullptr;
}
```

I was thinking how i should look at it. Its my first time using templates so i dont know how operator<< should look like.

Was thinking about something like:

```
friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & s, teamplate<something>);
```

But dont really know how to add it.
I need

```
cout << Database << endl;
```

to work properly.
Sorry for some polish language comments.

**Edit:**

I tried putting this friend declaration in the class Employee but i keep getting errors :(
code:

```
class Employee
{
private:

public:
Employee(string Name, string Position, int Age);
string Name;
int Age;
string Position;
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const map_template<Key, T> &map);
}
```

errors:

```
 maptemplate.h:49:63: error: ‘Key’ was not declared in this scope
 friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const map_template<Key, T> &map);
                                                           ^~~
 maptemplate.h:49:68: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
 friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const map_template<Key, T> &map);
                                                                ^
 maptemplate.h:49:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const map_template<Key, T> &map);
                                                                 ^
 maptemplate.h:49:69: error: template argument 2 is invalid
 maptemplate.h: In instantiation of ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const                     
 map_template<Key, T>&):
```

Should i change the declaration or what? I know that Key and T are in private. Maybe thats the case?
Anyone can help?
I'm a begginer so :/

Comment: Why not use an `std::map<ID, Employee>`?

Comment: Your Employee constructor, being an out-of-class definition in the header, will cause link errors if more than one .cpp file is compiled that includes your header.  (The function will be defined in every translation unit that includes your header.)  You have 3 choices: 1) define it inside the class declaration, 2) declare it "inline", or move it into a single .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisUzdavinis. Surely it would be a problem soon so much thanks!

Comment: "Making new friends" by "Dan Saks" explains the details about this really well

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
template <class Key, class T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const map_template<Key, T>& map) {
    // your logic on how to output the map here...
    return out;
}
```

so your `operator<<` will work with `map_template` of any specialization.

Obviously, your `friend` approach would also be suitable, plus you would actually drop the unnecessary `template` line. If you place your `operator <<` declaration inside your class, this:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const map_template<Key, T>& map) {
    // your logic on how to output the map here..
    return out;
}
```

will do just fine. Notice the lack of repeated `template <class Key, class T>`. Inside your class - those template types are visible and thus you can use them.

Comment: I made a post below. If you have a moment please help :)

Comment: Ok, made an edit to the first post! Sorry for the post before, im new there :D

Comment: @ObjectBeginner in class `Employee`, the second argument for `operator<<` should be `const Employee&`, not `const map_template<Key, T>&`. The operator that I provided in the answer will work when declared inside `map_template` class.